# Why do I get an index error whenever the program prints out a past guess list from the user?

Tags: python

I have to build a wordle project. Everything is fine except the fact that whenever past user guesses are printed on the terminal, i get a list out of index error. I have tried adding a word to the list already because I thought the error is happening because of index zero, however it's not working.
Here is my code. Also, ignore the ANSI escape codes.
My code:

```
import random as random
play_again="Y"
while play_again=="Y":
  count=0
  list_words=[]
  my_file = open("usaWords.txt", "r")
  data = my_file.read()
  # replacing end splitting the text 
  # when newline ('\n') is seen.
  word_list = data.split("\n")
  my_file.close()
  #generating a random number
  random_word=(random.choice(word_list))
  #re-generating a random number if duplicates or if digits less than 3
  #converting number into set because they dont allow duplicates
  while len((random_word)) !=5:
      random_word=(random.choice(word_list))
  print('\u001b[47;1m' + '\033[31m'+'Welcome to Wordle! You have six chances to guess the five-letter word. A letter G means you got that letter correct and in the right position. A letter Y means you matched that letter, but it is in the wrong position.A letter B means that letter does not appear in the correct word')

  def user_input():
      
      user_guess=input('Please enter your guess: ')
      guess_bad=True # Repeating below until the user gives a good input
      while guess_bad:
        if len(user_guess) !=5: #this should make sure that all digits can be converted to integers!
            print('Must contain five letters or more.')
            user_guess = input('Please enter a 5-letter word:')
        # elif len(set(str(user_guess))) <5:
        #         print('No duplicates.')
        #         user_guess = input('Please enter a 5-letter word. No duplicates:')
        else:
          guess_bad=False
      return user_guess
  #Docstring required within each function:
      """
          Description of function: This function will convert the words into lists to compare and output the answer to user. It also takes in the number of tries and outputs the count.
          return: The number of tries.
      """

 
  def add_user_lists(colored_guesses)->int: 
    background='\u001b[47;1m'
    user_guess=user_input()
    random_word_list=[]
    past_guess=['none']
    past_guess.append(user_guess)
    user_input_list=[]
    for letter in str(random_word):
      random_word_list.append(letter)
    for letter in str(user_guess):
      user_input_list.append(letter)
  #   Just to check the answers:  
    print(random_word_list)
    print(user_input_list)
    #save the colors here
    colored_guess=['B','B','B','B','B']
    #For storing the old guesses
    
    #This does greens
    for i in range (0, len(random_word_list)):
      if random_word_list[i]==user_input_list[i]:
        colored_guess[i]='G'
        
      elif random_word_list[i] in user_input_list:
        colored_guess[i]='Y'
      else:
        colored_guess[i]='B'
    #now you do all of the yellows

    colored_guesses.append(colored_guess)

    for i in range(len(colored_guesses)):
    
      print(f"{background} Guess {i+1} is {past_guess[i+1]} colors are {''.join(colored_guesses[i])}")

    return colored_guesses

  
  colored_guesses=[]
  temp=[]
  while len(temp)<6 and ['G','G','G','G','G'] not in temp:
    temp=add_user_lists(colored_guesses)
  if len(temp) >=6:
    print("You lost.")
  elif ['G','G','G','G','G'] in temp:
    print(f'you won! it took {len(temp)} tries!')
  play_again=(input("Do you want to play again? Y if yes, N if no: "))
```

I'm expecting to get responses like:
What is your guess? truck
Guess 1: slice  BBBBY
Guess 2: truck  BYBBB
What is your guess? delay
Guess 1: slice  BBBBY
Guess 2: truck  BYBBB
Guess 3: delay  BYBYB
What is your guess? wheat
Guess 1: slice  BBBBY
Guess 2: truck  BYBBB
Guess 3: delay  BYBYB
Guess 4: wheat  BBYYB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `colored_guesses` is longer then `past_guess`
So you can't index a non-existing index `past_guess[i+1]`
You probably want to iterate over `past_guess` instead.

If you wish to hold the `past_guess` you should append and not reset it every time.

Here is a small fix:

```
  def add_user_lists(colored_guesses, past_guess)->int: 
    background='\u001b[47;1m'
    user_guess=user_input()
    random_word_list=[]
    past_guess.append(user_guess)
    user_input_list=[]
    for letter in str(random_word):
      random_word_list.append(letter)
    for letter in str(user_guess):
      user_input_list.append(letter)
  #   Just to check the answers:  
    print(random_word_list)
    print(user_input_list)
    #save the colors here
    colored_guess=['B','B','B','B','B']
    #For storing the old guesses
    
    #This does greens
    for i in range (0, len(random_word_list)):
      if random_word_list[i]==user_input_list[i]:
        colored_guess[i]='G'
        
      elif random_word_list[i] in user_input_list:
        colored_guess[i]='Y'
      else:
        colored_guess[i]='B'
    #now you do all of the yellows

    colored_guesses.append(colored_guess)

    for i in range(len(past_guess)):
    
      print(f"{background} Guess {i} is {past_guess[i]} colors are {''.join(colored_guesses[i])}")

    return colored_guesses

  
  colored_guesses=[]
  temp=[]
  past_guess=[]
  while len(temp)<6 and ['G','G','G','G','G'] not in temp:
    temp=add_user_lists(colored_guesses, past_guess)
  if len(temp) >=6:
    print("You lost.")
  elif ['G','G','G','G','G'] in temp:
    print(f'you won! it took {len(temp)} tries!')
  play_again=(input("Do you want to play again? Y if yes, N if no: "))
```